Resource on the history of the Well-Ordering Principle (on the positive integers)
Can you recommend me a book or paper on the origin of what we nowadays call the Well-Ordering Principle of $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$?
I have several doubts regarding the provenance of this important principle. Who formulated it explicitly for the first time? I suppose that people would implicitly appeal to it in the days prior to E. Zermelo's epoch and that his contributions  to set theory had an influence in making textbook authors approach it in a more meticulous manner.
Any pointers you wish to provide on this topic are more than welcome!

Thanks... However, my question is specifically about the Well-Ordering Principle over the positive integers.

Are you looking for the original paper(s), or a contemporary account of that history?

A contemporary and down-to-earth account would suffice...

I don’t know of an account of the history (the book by Ewald mentioned below might say something about it in the introduction to Cantor’s paper?) But as far as I know, the concept of “well-ordering” is specifically described for the first time in section 2 of the paper by Cantor colloquially known as the “Grundlagen”
The original German is available here. English translations I know of are:

In volume 2 of the book From Kant To Hilbert by Ewald.
An online translation here (can’t really vouch for the accuracy of this one)

Update: Page 5 of this article by Akihiro Kanamori of Boston University states that

In his magisterial Grundlagen [1883] Cantor developed the transfinite numbers [Anzahlen] and the key concept of well-ordering

which certainly suggests that Cantor was the first to explicitly articulate the concept of well-ordering.
